# python import packages that know nothing about my system configuration

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have a project I am working on, let's call it Project, which lives in the directory `Project` somewhere wholly unknown to me (really it lives both on my local system and on a couple Docker build systems). In that project, I have some source files, `source/module1.py` and `source/module2.py`. I also have some example files, some test files, and an **init**.py So my directory looks something like this:

```
Project
  __init__.py
  /source
    module1.py
    module2.py
  /test
    testRunner.py
  /examples
    awesomeExample.py
```

However, `module1` needs some stuff from `module2`. My naive self thought this could be done by putting an import statement in module1:

```
import module2
# Do some other interesting stuff
```

And this works, *but only when I am running / importing module 1 from the source directory.* If I am, for example, running some unit tests in another directory `test/testRunner.py`, either from the `test` directory or in the main `Project` directory, the import will fail. Same with trying to use it when running an example in the `examples` directory.

So here is my problem: in general, I don't know where the calling script lives. It might be in the `examples` directory, it might be in the `test` directory, or it might be in the main `Project` directory (for example when trying to import stuff with an **init**.py). How do I ensure that `module1` can always import `module2` in each of these scenarios?

I am not looking for a solution like "add all those directories to your python path". Initially I just added `Project` to my python path on my local machine, and then did all my imports relative to that (`import Project.source.module2`), but this (predictably) caused my builds to fail on the Docker instances. I don't just want this to work on my local machine, but also on the Docker instances I'm using to build and test this software, and on any user's machine that subsequently installs it (i.e. by doing a `pip install Project`. What is the most robust way to make sure this dependency is satisfied? How can I make sure `module1` can import `module2` regardless of where `module1` itself is imported from? Any python 3.x.x solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it (credit [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/)) - it's a little inelegant, but extremely robust. Works on my local machine independent of whether using an `import` statement or running a script directly, as well as my build servers which use github actions and Travis CI.

Basically, I added a file in the `source` directory, called `context.py` with the following contents:

```
import os
import sys

fileLocation = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sourceLocation = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(fileLocation, '..', 'source/'))

sys.path.insert(0, sourceLocation)
```

This finds out the current file being executed from python, and then uses that to add to the python path. And then in my `module1.py` file, at the top I have:

```
import context
import module2
```

Now, whenever `module1` is imported, it successfully imports `module2`. More elegant answers or comments on why this works and in which cases it might fail are appreciated.

Comment: After publishing to pypi I found out this solution does not work if the package is installed on someone else's machine. It's also awkward messing with the user's path, I would rather not do that.